# Fill missing values in dataframe columns with column median in R

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I have a dataframe with some columns of type "factor" and others "numeric". There are no missing values in any of the "factor" columns.

I am trying to replace missing values in each column with column median using the following code:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df3)){
  df3[is.na(df3[,i]), i] <- median(df3[,i], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

However I am getting the error:

```
Error in median.default(df3[, i], na.rm = TRUE) : need numeric data
```

I am sure that there are missing values only in numeric column, why am I getting this error?

More importantly, how do I fill missing values in each column with respective column medians?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if `df3[is.na(df3[, i]), i]` has zero rows, R still needs to calculate the RHS `median(df3[,i], na.rm = TRUE)`. You could add a check to only replace missing values in numeric columns:

```
for(i in seq_along(df3)) {
  if (is.numeric(df3[, i])) {
    df3[is.na(df3[, i]), i] <- median(df3[, i], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}
```